# Positional tracking in Unity with Project Tango

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I'm using [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/blob/master/MotionTrackingUnity/Assets/Scripts/PoseController.cs) script from Google's Tango Unity Examples repository to control the movement of the camera in a Unity3D scene. It's meant to use the Tango's position and orientation tracking to move the camera correspondingly within Unity.

However, in the example scene it comes from, as well as the scene I've created, it seems that rotation is the only thing being tracked. No matter how far I move around (the real world), the camera is static. Rotation info transfers well, with no latency. From the snippet below, it looks like the code is correct - whenever the tango pose is available, it transforms the Tango coordinate frame matrix to Unity's, and extracts the position to set it in Unity.

```
public void OnTangoPoseAvailable(Tango.TangoPoseData pose)
    {
    ...
            // Converting from Tango coordinate frame to Unity coodinate frame.
            Matrix4x4 uwTuc = m_uwTss * ssTd * m_dTuc;

            // Extract new local position
            transform.position = uwTuc.GetColumn(3);

            // Extract new local rotation
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(uwTuc.GetColumn(2), uwTuc.GetColumn(1));
        }
     ...

    }
```

I've also ruled out the possibility that it's a hardware issue, because positional tracking is working well when I run the [Area Explorer](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/tools/explorer) and Cube Mover Tango demos.

Could this issue be a result of recent changes in Unity or the Tango API?

Comment: Have you tried `uwTuc.GetRow(3)` to rule out column-major vs row-major issues?

Comment: Did you check if your Environment is scaled properly? The Scale of the Environment may be so high , that the camera may appear to be not moving even with tiny additions.

Comment: Your code looks fine, are you doing any change to the sample code, I just pulled the master and compiled it. The position tracking works fine.

Comment: Also, I think another good test would be directly log out pose.translation and pose.orientation, see if the translation values are changing. The raw data won't be in the correct coordinate frame but at least you can see the data. If the data is changing, then it's just a matter of figuring out what happened before the transform.position = uwTuc.GetColumn(3);